How to write Khmer language in Latex overleaf
I want to write a document with khmer language in Latex overleaf. However, I don't know how to make it happen.
I try babel and fail. I also search many way to write it but it end up doesn't work. Please anyone can help me how I can write the language I want in Latex overleaf.

If you have a font with the necessary letters, you could use lualatex and the fontspec package. Please add a short test document to your question.

Sorry I don't know how to add short test document
